# Master node needs to execute mdpboot everytime after fresh restart of system

Tags: cluster-computing, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, mpich

I have to explicitly boot all the processor nodes every time when my master system restarts
i.e

`mdpboot -n 3`

P.S
I am implementing beowulf cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to a new version of MPICH. MPD is quite old and hasn't been supported for some time. The newer versions use Hydra which doesn't require booting.

Comment: since i'm using the ubunto 10.04 and when i download mpich2, my kernel by default downloaded mpich verison 1.2.1 and for mpich version 1.2x i cannot use hydra

Comment: You can always install the latest version yourself from source or use some of the prebuilt binaries that are available at the bottom of the http://www.mpich.org/downloads page.